# hidden div and showing div making radio buttons not work jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, radio-button, refresh

I have a div that starts out hidden on page load, then it is shown when a user clicks a button.

This div contains more buttons which open up a jQuery mobile popup. These popups have radio buttons on them. The radio buttons show, but when you click on them, they don't switch which one is checked. Any ideas how to fix this? I think something with a refresh would do it, but I tried a few different things with no success.

```
<div class="ui-grid-b center hide" id="grid-2">
                <div class="ui-block-a gridRows">
                    <h2 class="labelText">LS1</h2>
                    <a href="#LS1popup" data-rel="popup" onClick="strobeBackground();"><img src="images/LEDoff.gif" id="LS1LED" class="LED"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b gridRows">
                    <h2 class="labelText">LS2</h2>
                    <a href="#LS2popup" data-rel="popup" id="" onClick="strobeBackground();"><img src="images/LEDoff.gif" id="LS2LED" class="LED"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c gridRows">
                    <h2 class="labelText">MS</h2>
                    <a href="#MSpopup" data-rel="popup" id="" onClick="strobeBackground();"><img src="images/LEDoff.gif" id="MSLED" class="LED"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This div below has the popup and radio buttons

```
<div data-role="popup" id="LS1popup" data-theme="d">
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>               
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="true">
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-icon="">
                      <li>Edit LS1 LED</li>
                    </ul>
                      <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1off" value="off" onClick="setImages();" data-theme="b" checked="checked"/>
                      <label for="LS1off">Off</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1green" value=" green" onClick="setImages();" data-theme="b"/>
                      <label for="LS1green">Green</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1flashinggreen" value="flashinggreen" onClick="setImages();"  data-theme="b"/>
                      <label for="LS1flashinggreen">Flashing Green</label>
                      <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1yellow" value="yellow" onClick="setImages();"  data-theme="b"/>
                      <label for="LS1yellow">Yellow</label>
                </fieldset>
        </div><!-- /popup -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I found the right radio button refresh for jQuery

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/AeXnV/ Click image under LS1 and see.

And what `setImages()` function is doing?

```
<div data-role="popup" id="LS1popup" data-theme="d">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>               
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="true">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d" data-icon="">
                  <li>Edit LS1 LED</li>
                </ul>
                  <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1off" value="off" onClick="setImages();" data-theme="b" checked="checked"/>
                  <label for="LS1off">Off</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1green" value=" green" onClick="setImages();" data-theme="b"/>
                  <label for="LS1green">Green</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1flashinggreen" value="flashinggreen" onClick="setImages();"  data-theme="b"/>
                  <label for="LS1flashinggreen">Flashing Green</label>
                  <input type="radio" name="LS1" id="LS1yellow" value="yellow" onClick="setImages();"  data-theme="b"/>
                  <label for="LS1yellow">Yellow</label>
            </fieldset>
    </div><!-- /popup -->
```

Comment: It is working find there because the divs aren't originally hidden.

setImages() changes the images for each thing, so when LS1 is changed, if its set to LS1 green, then the image turns to green, if LS1yellow is selected, then the image turns to a yellow one.

Also ignore the strobeBackground onClick thing, that was there by mistake.

Comment: So there is a button. When you click it, the divs with the other popup buttons are shown. when you click one of those, it opens a popup with a bunch of radio buttons. The radio buttons work when you click on them, but they don't visible show which one is selected.